# Getting NPE at p2.console

Tags: eclipse, equinox, p2, eclipse-ecf

I am getting NPE exception for `p2.console` while accessing it.

```
osgi> provaddrepo http://localhost:8080/Site
gogo: NullPointerException: null
osgi> provaddmetadatarepo http://localhost:8080/Site
gogo: NullPointerException: null
osgi> provinstall org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 0.8.4
gogo: NullPointerException: null
osgi>
```

I am also getting same exception from my custom mail application.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at 
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadIndexFile(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:721)
```

I didnot understand the meaning of "no transport available"
Or how to check transport bundles. I checked ecf bundles which were installed on my equinox.
I am using eclipse juno

Do anyone has any solution, tutorial for p2.console etc ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a bundle in your Equinox runtime that provides the transport service for p2. AFAIK, p2 only provides one implementation of that service, which is in the bundle `org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf`.

For a full list of bundles needed to make p2 work, you can for example consult [this product definition](http://git.eclipse.org/c/tycho/org.eclipse.tycho.git/tree/tycho-bundles/tycho-bundles-external/tycho-bundles-external.product) in the Tycho project sources.